# When is the enveloping algebra finitely generated over its center as a module?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Let $g$ be a Lie algebra with enveloping algebra $U(g)$ and $Z(g)$ the center of $U(g)$.

> Question 1: When is $Z(g)$ noetherian?

> Question 2: When is $U(g)$ a finitely generated $Z(g)$-module? Is this true when $g$ is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 3):

For Question 2, I think the answer is "very rarely" in characteristic 0 (unless $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian).

For example, let $\mathfrak{g} = \langle x, y, z\rangle_{\mathbb{C}}$ with relation $[x,y] = z$ and $[x,z] = [y,z] = 0$. It follows that $Z(\mathfrak{g}) = \mathbb{C}[z]$. Indeed, let
$$
a = \sum_{m, n, l\in \mathbb{N}} c_{m, n, l}x^my^nz^l\in Z(\mathfrak{g}),\quad c_{m,n,l}\in \mathbb{C}.
$$
Then we have
$$
[x,a] = \sum_{\substack{m, n, l\in \mathbb{N} \\ n \ge 1}}n c_{m, n, l}x^my^{n-1}z^{l+1}
$$
so $c_{m,n,l} = 0$ unless $n = 0$. Similarly, $c_{m,n,l} = 0$ unless $m = 0$.

However, in characteristic $p > 0$, for an arbitrary Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ we have
$$
U(\mathfrak{g}^p) = \mathbb{k}[x^p\;;\;x\in \mathfrak{g}]\subset Z(\mathfrak{g})
$$
so $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is a finite $Z(\mathfrak{g})$-module provided that $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks, how is the situation when $g$ is semisimple in characteristic 0?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism

Comment: Thanks, so it is module-finite when g is semisimple and the characteristic is 0?! (it seems wikipedia doesnt say it explicitly)

Comment: Ah no, sorry. I said something idiot. In the semisimple case the centre $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a ring of symmetric polynomial of dimension equal to the rank of $\mathfrak{g}$, which is smaller than the dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$. It's not module finite.

Comment: Thanks, is the universal enveloping algebra for a semisimple g module-finite over some other (canonical) commutative noetherian ring?

Comment: I don't think so. There is a theorem of Beilinson--Bernstein saying that $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the ring of twisted differential operators on the flag variety of $G$. This kind of algebras doesn't have large commutative subalgebra.